# Header equivalent of PHP include

Tags: c#, asp.net, include

I originally come from PHP and I have just started with ASP/.NET.  I am aware that a direct equivalent of `include("filename.php");` does not exist, but that's not exactly what I want to achieve.

I am attempting to create a header file which I can use on every page.  I have read from many sources that making a user control is the solution. After creating all of the necessary code to make this work, I arrived at a point where the actual element on the page isn't actually created at the point when I call .InnerHtml.  For example:

```
breadcrumbContainer.InnerHtml = "testing text";
```

The above code does not work when called within my file which is called `header.ascx.cs` even though there is a div on the page with `runat="server"` and the correct ID.

I am trying to find out if there is an easier way to resolve this problem.  I have been told that I should avoid masterpages (even though I don't know if they are relevant in this situation). Should I create some sort of method which creates the html for the header, this way I can easily call it on every page? Are there any other solutions I haven't thought of?

If there are any good articles which clearly explain this problem, I would love the links.  I have literally searched hundreds of pages on the web and found nothing that is giving me a clear understanding of how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master pages can be relevant and very helpful in this case. [Check out them out.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)!

When someone says "don't do something" always ask why. Do not take such advice at face value. That's exactly how phantom fears are spread and thousands of developers end of treating some programmer's pet peeve as an an absolute rule! Besides, asking "why?" will strengthen your own as well as the more senior developer's understanding of the issue at hand.

From the link:

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the
>   pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and
>   feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a
>   group of pages) in your application. You can then create individual
>   content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users
>   request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce
>   output that combines the layout of the master page with the content
>   from the content page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am looking into the master pages and you seem right that it's exactly what I am looking for!  The "don't do something" reason appears to be that working with jQuery and master pages seems to cause a lot of problems with the IDs.  I am attempting to resolve this problem now.